# cakephp not loading java applet inside view

Tags: java, cakephp, applet

I have this java applet, composed by an index.html and a few other files. If I put the folder of the java applet with all its files inside the webroot of my CakePHP app and I access the index.html file through the navigation bar of the browser (i.e. www.mydomain.com/applet_folder/index.html) it all works perfectly.

However, if I have a view and I place an iframe that loads that same location, then the applet doesn't work. It shows the index.html contents, but the applet itself doesn't do anything. The same happens if I put the code of the index.html file into the view (instead of just loading it with an iframe), doesn't work.

So it's like if I access it with using a view, the same exact code gets messed up. I've tried changing the paths that the applet uses, even using absolute paths, to see if it could be that cake was messing up my paths, but still the same.

Any ideas why this might be happening?

In case someone wonders, I'm using the following applet: http://www.vimas.com/mp3.php

Comment: I don't know if you found soluytion, but what I did is that I placed the applet inside default.ctp in Layouts section. So Applet starts from the main component. While I didn't test it in a seperate view, because Ajax loading the view didn't trigger the applet!! My solution was that.

Answer (score 0):

Place the jar and other applet related files in the webroot/files and in your cake code set path to the same. by default cakephp searches for files in the webroot